# Component scan to avoid scanning tst folder

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit

We are using spring's component-scan and don't want application context to load test beans (even if they are defined in the same path i.e a.b.c).

```
MyPackage
    src
        a.b.c.SRC
    tst
        a.b.c.TST
```

I have read that order would be to load src folder first and then the test folder. In above case, if I component-scan a.b.c, I only want to load beans from SRC. How is that possible?

Comment: Why not use `<context:component-scan base-package="a.b.c.SRC" />`?

Comment: Because there are multiple config classes in a.b.c and they will have to be imported explicitly.

Comment: Arguably the best option would be not to have any test-only Spring components at all.

Comment: I agree to what @kryger is saying. 'don't want application context to load test beans' is kind of confusing. Are you loading application context containing test beans during your application startup? If it is the case, then its a wrong practice and you may want to refactor your application context xml files or configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @Profile("ProfileName") annotation on your components and of course setting the active profile on execution. The Component Scan will ignore beans that dont match the active profile. e.g.

```
@Component
@Profile("production")
public class productionImpl implements SomeInterface{}

@Component
@Profile("test")
public class testImpl implements SomeInterface{}
```

All you have to do after that is setting the correct profile in live execution. You can set it either as a JVM argument (spring.profiles.active) or set it to the applicationContext: `ApplicationContext.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles(“ProfileName”);`

For your test execution classes you can use @ActiveProfiles("TestProfileName")

You can check this site for a more detailed example: http://websystique.com/spring/spring-profile-example/

Answer (score 0):

There are several exclude filters for classpath scanning you can define in your context configuration file. `aspectj` filter type seems to be the one you would want to use.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="a.b.c">  
    <context:exclude-filter type="aspectj" expression="a.b.c.TST.*" />  
</context:component-scan>
```

Alternatively, if you would like to have a bit more granularity, you can define your own annotation and use the `annotation` exclude-filter type.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="path.to.your.package.ScanExclude"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

This way, all classes annotated with `@ScanExclude` annotation are effectively ignored